# Prolog - Finding object with shortest inner List in a List

Tags: list, variables, recursion, binding, prolog

I have a large list `BIGLIST` that consists solely of any number of smaller lists `SMALLLIST`, which themselves contain another list `INNERLIST` in their first index. I need to design a predicate that can find the `SMALLLIST` with the shortest `INNERLIST`. No `INNERLIST` has a length greater than 9. For example:

```
BIGLIST = [
          [[1,2,3],3824],
          [[4,5],89],
          [[6],283],
          [[2],14],
          ]
```

The `SMALLLIST` with the shortest `INNERLIST` here is `[[6],283]`, despite the existence of `[[2],14]` (they are the same length). I've written a predicate `shortest/2` like the following, but the desired `SMALLLIST` never gets bound to `Shortest`:

```
shortest(BIGLIST,Shortest) :-
    Num = 10,
    get_shortest(BIGLIST,Shortest,Num).

get_shortest([],_,_).                                 %list is empty, stop
get_shortest([SMALLLIST|Tail],Shortest,ShortLen) :-   %better SMALLLIST found
    nth0(0,SMALLLIST,INNERLIST),                           %get INNERLIST
    length(INNERLIST,Len),
    Len < ShortLen,
    NShortest = SMALLLIST,
    NShortLen = Len,
    get_shortest(Tail,NShortest,NShortLen),
    Shortest = NShortest.
get_shortest([_|T],Shortest,ShortLen) :-             %skip head if it is not a better value
    get_shortest(T,Shortest,ShortLen).
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could do something like, `setof( N-[L|T], (member([L|T], BIGLIST), length(L, N)), S ), S = [_-SMALLIST|_].` but it will pick the last of the shortest if there's a "tie", rather than the first.

Comment: `Head` should be `SMALLLIST`, but there are other flaws in your code. Have you considered using `->`? And if you just want the head, use `[INNERLIST|_]=SMALLLIST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases `keysort/2` comes in handy. For example:

```
biglist_smallest(Bs, E) :-
        maplist(element_with_length, Bs, LEs),
        keysort(LEs, [_-E|_]).

element_with_length(Elem, L-Elem) :-
        Elem = [Inner|_],
        length(Inner, L).
```

With your data:

```
biglist([[[1,2,3],3824],
         [[4,5],89],
         [[6],283],
         [[2],14]
         ]).
```

we get:

```
?- biglist(Ls), biglist_smallest(Ls, E).
Ls = [[[1, 2, 3], 3824], [[4, 5], 89], [[6], 283], [[2], 14]],
E = [[6], 283].
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out like 10 minutes later, did something like this:

```
shortest(BIGLIST,Shortest) :-
    Num = 10,
    get_shortest(BIGLIST,Num,_,Shortest).

get_shortest([],_,S,S).
get_shortest([SMALLLIST|Tail],ShortLen,_,Result) :-
    nth0(0,SMALLLIST,INNERLIST),
    length(INNERLIST,Len),
    Len < ShortLen,
    NShortest = SMALLLIST,
    NShortLen = Len,
    get_shortest(Tail,NShortLen,NShortest,Result).
get_shortest([_|T],ShortLen,Shortest,Result) :- 
    get_shortest(T,ShortLen,Shortest,Result).
```